# Orthogonal Diagonalization of a $3$ by $3$ Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, orthogonal-matrices

**$M$ $=$ $\begin{pmatrix}3&2&2\\ 2&3&2\\ 2&2&3\end{pmatrix}$. Diagonalize $M$ using an orthogonal matrix.**

So I got that the eigenvalues for $M$ were $1$ and $7$. For the eigenvalue of $1$, I got the eigenvectors $\begin{pmatrix}-1\\ 0\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}-1\\ 1\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$, and for the eigenvalue of $7$, I got the eigenvector $\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 1\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$. This gave me the diagonal matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0&7\end{pmatrix}$ and the orthogonal matrix $\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\\ 0&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&0&\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\end{pmatrix}$.

But when I multiply the orthogonal matrix by the diagonal matrix and then its transpose, I get an answer that is slightly off what $M$ is, but I am not sure why.

If anyone knows where I may have gone wrong, I would greatly appreciate you telling me!

Comment: Both eigenvectors for $\;\lambda=1\;$ are wrong, as you can easily check. The eigenvectors corresponding to different eigenvalues are orthogonal (because the matrix is symmetric), so you must only do GM in each eigenspace...

Answer (score 1):

$$(-1, 0, 1) \cdot (-1, 1, 0)=1$$

They are not orthogonal.

Just do a gram-schmidt step to find a set of orthogonal eigenvectors for eigenvalues corresponding to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

start with

$$    
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr}
  1  &  -1  &  -1    \\
  1  &  1  &  -1     \\
  1  &  0  &  2     \\
\end{array}
\right).
$$
 and divide the columns by $\sqrt 3, \sqrt 2, \sqrt 6$

If you had the analogous problem in 4 by 4, you could begin with

$$    
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr}
  1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1    \\
  1  &  1  &  -1  &  -1     \\
  1  &  0  &  2  &  -1     \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  3     \\
\end{array}
\right).
$$
and divide the columns by $2,\sqrt 2, \sqrt 6, \sqrt {12}$

for 5 by 5
$$    
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr}
  1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1    \\
  1  &  1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1    \\
  1  &  0  &  2  &  -1  &  -1    \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  3  &  -1    \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  4    \\
  \end{array}
\right).
$$
 $\sqrt 5,\sqrt 2, \sqrt 6, \sqrt {12}, \sqrt{20}$